# Visual Studio 2015 crashes with FileNotFoundException

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Each time when I'm trying to open any .cs file as part of some solution with VS 2015 Pro, it crashes with System.IO.FileNotFoundException:

```
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Sounds strange, reflecting the part that the VS 2015 doesn't have any additional extensions and tools. Also, I've tried to repair/reinstall that, tried using \SafeMode parameter. It doesn't work.

What might be a reason of such behavior? Should I manually install that assembly? If yes, then which directory it must be? Gac?

P.S. I found out that assembly already located in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies`

P.P.S. It looks like the reason of these failings is CodeLens feature. When this feature is off I'm not observing crashes. Here is possible temporary workaround: just switch off the CodeLens feature.

Comment: In error message, there is also writen ...`or one of its dependencies.`. There still can be something missing. I would take [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) and track down which exact files are being located at the time of opening the project by the VS. This could give you more information what is happening.

Comment: You should post this as a Connect with microsoft.  We can't answer this question.  Could be anything from physical issues with your machine, viruses/antivirus software, corrupt OS, bad install media, etc etc.  All we can tell you is that this is NOT normal.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have the same problem..

Comment: @Luke, no I didn't. In september I created a feedback, but it is still active hovewer there are comments from Microsoft guys. To be honest, this is very annoying that I can't use VS 2015 while I do have an MSDN subscribtion.

Comment: We are having this issue now since installing the reporting services templates..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I diagnose and fix a Visual Studio 2015 crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850977/how-do-i-diagnose-and-fix-a-visual-studio-2015-crash)

Comment: So, what I've got so far from MS is just recommendation to reinstall VS. I suppose I should close the topic, since it's not relevant now when 2017 has been released and this issue is not reproducible anymore.