# Visual 2015 not starting up because of a System.IO.FileNotFoundException. How do I fix this?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, startup, filenotfoundexception

Visual Studio pops up then instantly disappears. I have repaired it and restarted my computer. 
I am currently working on custom reports in Visual Studio and have installed all the necessary components listed here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531081.aspx. 
This issue only appeared after I installed all the components in the aforementioned link.

Below are the event details from the event viewer:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.Common.CommonUtilities.ResetUserTokenStorage(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.AccountManagement.IAccountManager)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.UserInformation.UserInformationDataSource.SignoutAndClearKeychain()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.UserInformation.UserInformationDataSource.UserInformationCommandHandler(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIDispatch, System.String, System.Object, System.Object ByRef)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.UIDispatch.Invoke(System.String, System.Object, System.Object ByRef)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.UserInformation.UserInformationDataSource.PrepareForFirstLaunchSignIn()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.UserInformation.UserInformationDataSource.UserInformationCommandHandler(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIDispatch, System.String, System.Object, System.Object ByRef)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.UIDispatch.Invoke(System.String, System.Object, System.Object ByRef)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.DataSource.Invoke(System.String, System.Object, System.Object ByRef)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.UserInformation.FirstLaunchSignIn.FirstLaunchSignIn_Loaded(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastEvent(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEvent)
   at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastLoadedEvent(System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.LoadedOrUnloadedOperation.DoWork()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireLoadedPendingCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Resize(System.Windows.Media.ICompositionTarget)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DefWndProcWrapper(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

Comment: Seems like your not the only one.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484974/visual-studio-2015-crashes-with-filenotfoundexception

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I diagnose and fix a Visual Studio 2015 crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850977/how-do-i-diagnose-and-fix-a-visual-studio-2015-crash)

Comment: You have to love Microsoft, after 30 years they haven't learned to properly report file file ot found errors. I'm getting this in 2017 now. Guessing I'm going to have to reinstall. I tried the repair option on the installer and didn't fix it. Looks like it failed loading some WPF file in my case